# Get redirect location in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script which I call from cron and redirecting its output into a file.

Crontab is filled with another script, which also generate the location of stdout redirection which can change depending on many factors.

I would like to know, in my script, to what file stdout is redirected.

Is there a way to accomplish this without any config files or passing the file location as argument to script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readlink -f /proc/$$/fd/1`

`$$` ... pid of the running script

`/proc/[pid]/fd/1` ... 1 is file descriptor of stdout, it's represented as a symbolic link to the actual file

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lsof`; there might be an easier way to limit the output to just the file name.

```
lsof -d 1 -a -p $$ -Fn | awk '/^n/ { print substr($1, 2); }'
```

This is useful if your operating system does not have a `/proc` file system.

Answer (score 0):

From your shell script, you can use:

```
/proc/$$/fd/1
```

which is the stdout of your shell process (`$$`).

You can try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

readlink /proc/$$/fd/1
```

If you call this script.sh, run `script.sh > /tmp/f.out`
When you read the contents of the file `/tmp/f.out` it'll be:

```
/tmp/f.out
```